# How to find documents in ArangoDB which have a certain date (range) in an array?

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to find all documents within a collection that have events within a certain date range.

Simplified the document structure looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Example document",
    "other": "property",
    "date_events": [
        {
            "start": "1963-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "1963-10-13T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "start": "1970-04-20T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "1970-04-20T12:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are *n* documents, which all have the property `date_events`, which is an array of objects, containing *n* events, each event has `start` and `end`.

Now I want to find all documents which have events within a certain date range, eg. between `1970-04-10` and `1970-04-28`:

```sql
FOR doc IN api_documents
    FILTER (doc.date_events[*].start ANY >= "1970-04-10T00:00:00.000Z" &&
        doc.date_events[*].end ANY <= "1970-04-28T12:00:00.000Z")
    RETURN { _key: doc._key, _id: doc._id, events: doc.date_events[*] }
```

The problem is, that the above query is incorrect and the result contains also documents that have no matching events whatsoever, eg. this one:

```json
{
    "name": "False positive",
    "other": "property",
    "date_events": [
        {
            "start": "1966-02-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "1966-02-24T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "start": "1979-11-26T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "1979-11-30T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "start": "1980-01-31T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "1980-01-31T12:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get it to work when only filtering for one property, eg. `start`. But as soon as both `start` and `end` is in the query, all the queries that I was able to come up with, either produce zero results or false positives, which do not match the input date range.

Is the usage of the `ANY` operator incorrectly here when looking for two properties or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query returns every document that includes `date_events` that fit either criterion.

To make sure both criteria are matched by a single `date_event`, you can filter `date_events` in a sub-query and then filter for non empty results, something like this (untested, but should get you started):

```
FOR doc IN api_documents
    LET matches = (
        FOR de IN doc.date_events
            FILTER de.start >= "1970-04-10T00:00:00.000Z" &&
                   de.end <= "1970-04-28T12:00:00.000Z"
            RETURN 1
    )
    FILTER LENGTH(matches) > 0
    RETURN { _key: doc._key, _id: doc._id, events: doc.date_events }
```